# Filling in form fields when going back and forth webpages

Tags: php, html, forms, session

I've looked around (here at stackoverflow and with Google) but I can't seem to figure out why my form values disappear when I go backwards and then forwards on a web survey. I have three pages I'm experimenting with. If I go through the survey answering each question, and then go backwards the values are preserved. But, my values for the second and third page are no longer filled in if I re-answer the question on the first page and press submit. However, the array listed out at the top still shows it. Shouldn't the PHP code in the form itself repopulate the values from the session array until a user changes them?

I'm also aware that the method I'm using for storing all POST values into a session is dangerous but I plan to only write this to a plain .txt file. Thank you for any help!

Page 1

```
<?php
// begin the session
ini_set('session.cache_limiter', 'private');
session_start();
// Take each input name and create a variable for it
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v) {
$_SESSION[$k]=$v;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>This is a test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" name="Gender" action="page2.php">
<p>What is your gender?</p>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="male" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['male'])) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } else { echo $gender = ''; } ?>> <label for="male">Male</label> <br />
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="female" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['female'])) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } else { echo $gender = ''; }?>> <label for="female">Female</label><br />

<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Page 2

```
<?php
// begin the session
ini_set('session.cache_limiter', 'private');
session_start();
// Take each input name and create a variable for it
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v) {
$_SESSION[$k]=$v;
}
// Prints out the session array
print('<input type="hidden" name="' . $k . '" value="' . $v . '" />'); 
Print_r ($_SESSION);
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>This is a test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" name="lolz" action="page3.php">
<p>What is your lolz?</p>
<input type="radio" name="lolz" value="YesLOLZ" id="YesLOLZ" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['YesLOLZ'])) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } else { echo $lolz = ''; } ?>> <label for="YesLOLZ">YesLOLZ</label> <br />
<input type="radio" name="lolz" value="NoLOLZ" id="NoLOLZ" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['NoLOLZ'])) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } else { echo $lolz = ''; } ?>> <label for="NoLOLZ">NoLOLZ</label><br />

<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Page 3

```
<?php
// begin the session
ini_set('session.cache_limiter', 'private');
session_start();
// Take each input name and create a variable for it
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v) {
$_SESSION[$k]=$v;
}
// Prints out the session array
print('<input type="hidden" name="' . $k . '" value="' . $v . '" />'); 
Print_r ($_SESSION);
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>This is a test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" name="lolz" action="page3.php">
<p>What is your roflz?</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="roflz[]" value="Yesroflz" id="Yesroflz" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['Yesroflz'])) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } else { echo ''; } ?>> <label for="Yesroflz">Yesroflz</label> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="roflz[]" value="Noroflz" id="Noroflz" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['Noroflz'])) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } else { echo ''; } ?>> <label for="Noroflz">Noroflz</label><br />

<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this doesn't work, please screenshot/copy+paste what appears in response to `print_r($_SESSION);` & report any PHP errors you get, even if they're just notice-level.

So far you've done the following:

- Starting a session has to be the very first thing on the page to be successful.  You should have been getting the error Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent in ...  By moving the `session_start()` up this was fixed.
- You are copying the $_POST array into $_SESSION on every page.
- You ensured that you were consistently using the $_SESSION superglobal rather than the $_POST superglobal when checking for values.

Now you need to:

- Ensure you are using a `foreach` loop and the appropriate variable name to output hidden inputs.  You should be getting an error that reads Notice: Undefined variable: k in line 9 ... etc.
- Ensure you are using the correct array key when checking for the value of a field.  The key in the $_POST (and therefore $_SESSION) array will match the `name` attribute of the `input` while the value will match the `value` attribute of the `input`.

**If you haven't gotten any of these errors try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to line 5 (right after `session_start();`).  This line should be used only during development and taken out when you release the code.**

**Page 1**

```
<?php
    // begin the session
    ini_set('session.cache_limiter', 'private');
    session_start();
    // Take each input name and create a variable for it
    foreach($_POST as $k=>$v) {
        $_SESSION[$k]=$v;
    }
    // Prints out the session array
    print_r($_SESSION);
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>This is a test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" name="Gender" action="page2.php">
        <p>
            What is your gender?
        </p>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="male" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['gender']) && $_SESSION['gender'] == "male") { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>>
        <label for="male">
            Male
        </label>
        <br />
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="female" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['gender']) && $_SESSION['gender'] == "female") { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>>
        <label for="female">
            Female
        </label>
        <br />
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Page 2**

```
<?php
    // begin the session
    ini_set('session.cache_limiter', 'private');
    session_start();
    // Take each input name and create a variable for it
    foreach($_POST as $k=>$v) {
        $_SESSION[$k]=$v;
    }
    // Prints out the session array
    print_r($_SESSION);
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>This is a test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" name="lolz" action="page3.php">
        <?php
            foreach($_SESSION as $k=>$v) {
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . $k . '" value="' . $v . '" />';
            }
        ?>
        <p>
            What is your lolz?
        </p>
        <input type="radio" name="lolz" value="YesLOLZ" id="YesLOLZ" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['lolz']) && $_SESSION['lolz'] == "YesLOLZ") { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>>
        <label for="YesLOLZ">
            YesLOLZ
        </label>
        <br />
        <input type="radio" name="lolz" value="NoLOLZ" id="NoLOLZ" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['lolz']) && $_SESSION['lolz'] == "NoLOLZ") { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>>
        <label for="NoLOLZ">
            NoLOLZ
        </label>
        <br />
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Page 3**

```
<?php
    // begin the session
    ini_set('session.cache_limiter', 'private');
    session_start();
    // Take each input name and create a variable for it
    foreach($_POST as $k=>$v) {
        $_SESSION[$k]=$v;
    }
    // Prints out the session array
    print_r($_SESSION);
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>This is a test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" name="lolz" action="page3.php">
        <?php
            foreach($_SESSION as $k=>$v) {
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . $k . '" value="' . $v . '" />';
            }
        ?>
        <p>
            What is your roflz?
        </p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="roflz" value="Yesroflz" id="Yesroflz" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['roflz']) && $_SESSION['lolz'] == "Yesroflz") { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>>
        <label for="Yesroflz">
            Yesroflz
        </label>
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="roflz" value="Noroflz" id="Noroflz" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['roflz']) && $_SESSION['lolz'] == "Noroflz") { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>>
        <label for="Noroflz">
            Noroflz
        </label>
        <br />
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and as well as jeroen's suggestion and my values are still being lost. Does it matter if I'm print $_SESSION though? I'll eventually remove it but I was using it to see if the values were being stored in the session.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't read closely enough and was looking at the wrong spot (it wasn't about print/echo it was about $_POST being empty even though $_SESSION might not be).  Try my updated answer, to replace the line print(...).  But I think you should probably use both of my code blocks unless I'm really confused about what you're trying to do with the radio fields :-)

Comment: With the radio fields (and checkboxes) I'm trying to use to re-select the selected responses if the participant has already answered them (via retrieval from session). I've since tried using $_SESSION instead of $_POST since $_SESSION should be persistent but it doesn't automatically select the responses on page2.php if they change their answer on page1.php. The end goal is to reduce the burden on whoever is using this form so they don't have to re-select all their answers if they only want to change one answer.

Comment: Please see my updated response.  @jeroen is right, you should be getting notices that $k and $v aren't defined, because the line on line 9 `print('<input type="hidden" name="' . $k . '" value="' . $v . '" />'); ` those variables don't exist, they're only available inside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Oh, also, I just updated it again, because I noticed another issue.  You're checking the wrong key.  The key will be the @name attribute (NOT @id) and the value will be the @value attribute.  Your code was showing the @value/@id attribute as the key in $_SESSION.

Comment: Thanks! The `&& $_SESSION['key'] == "value")` was the key missing part I think (for re-selecting the response). I wish I could give everyone here a check though. :(. Especially @jeroen since his comments were also helpful.

Comment: It was definitely a process!  I've given @jeroen a vote for usefulness.  Glad I could help along with others.

Answer (score 2):

Your sessions are not working because the headers already have been sent. You are outputting html before the `session_start` statement and you can´t do that if you want to use sessions.

Just move your `html` tag down to below the first php block and make sure there are no spaces or new-lines before the opening php tag.

**Edit:** Based on your comments, I think you need to do the following at the start of all php files of the form:

1. start and read the session
2. read the `$_POST` values and add / overwrite them in your `$_SESSION` variables
   (the session now contains the newly posted and previously posted information)
3. use `$_SESSION` instead of `$_POST` variables in your form where you set the values, so:
   `<?php if (isset($_SESSION['YesLOLZ'])) { echo 'checked="checked"'; }`
   instead of:
   `<?php if (isset($_POST['YesLOLZ'])) { echo 'checked="checked"'; }`

Also note that the variables `$k` and `$v` do not really *exist* outside your `while` loop; they do exist, but contain information of the last `$_POST` variable, probably the send button so you can't really use them.

Comment: So like this? 
`<?php
// begin the session
ini_set('session.cache_limiter', 'private');
session_start();
?>
<html>`

I tried placing `ini_set('session.cache_limiter', 'private');` after the session_start statement but then the cache was refreshing. It didn't seem to solve the problem though (I also implemented rhyaniwyn's recommendation).

Comment: @OneBigNewbie Have you tried a `var_dump($_SESSION)` right after `session_start()`?

Comment: It dawns upon me that my question may be poorly worded (I apologize). The Session does capture the data across pages. My problem is how to repopulate the form (e.g. radio buttons are selected) if the user selected them. The goal is to reduce the workload on the user so they won't have to re-answer all questions if they want to change one previous answer.

Comment: @OneBigNewbie I see what the problem is, take a look at my edit.

Comment: I've tried that although it doesn't seem to work. I've (accidentally) found that if I use `<?php if (isset($_SESSION['NAMEOFINPUT(e.g.gender)'])) { echo 'checked="checked"'; }` then it checks the question on the form. However, I need to somehow make it match the value. So if it's gender = male then select male. Or if gender = female select female. In its current form with the change from input value to input name it just checks the last radio input that matches its name.

Comment: @OneBigNewbie checkboxes are tricky; the value does not really matter, if they are checked they are posted and if they are not checked, they are not (and you are not removing them from the session if they are not posted, so they remain set although they might not be checked this time...). Perhaps you need radio inputs?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are storing the answers in the session but not checking it when you want to see if you should automatically fill in a certain input. The post values are not persistent so if you go back and restart the quiz from page one then only the values from page one will be in the post variable. When you submit page two, you actually lose everything from the POST in page one but since you are storing it in the session you still have access to it.

Comment: So if I echo Session variables it should theoretically return the value? Like so? `<?php if (isset($_SESSION['Yesroflz'])) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } else { echo ''; } ?>`. If that's the case it isn't working. :(